# FLUTTER_ NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

I did research from many source about this error but i've found nothing. I'm trying to build a ListView.builder in Flutter, where the itemBuilder is from my JSON response data like this:

My event Model was generated for me like

```
Events eventsFromJson(String str) => Events.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventsToJson(Events data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Events {
  Events({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
    required this.total,
  });

  bool status;
  String message;
  Data data;
  int total;

  factory Events.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Events(
    status: json["status"],
    message: json["message"],
    data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "message": message,
    "data": data.toJson(),
    "total": total,
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.events,
  });

  List<Event> events;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    events: List<Event>.from(json["events"].map((x) => Event.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "events": List<dynamic>.from(events.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Event {
  Event({
    required this.id,
    required this.eventName,
    required this.eventType,
    required this.eventLocation,
    required this.checkInDate,
    required this.checkOutDate,
    required this.eventImage,
  });

  String id;
  String eventName;
  String eventType;
  String eventLocation;
  DateTime checkInDate;
  DateTime checkOutDate;
  String eventImage;

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    id: json["id"],
    eventName: json["event_name"],
    eventType: json["event_type"],
    eventLocation: json["event_location"],
    checkInDate: DateTime.parse(json["check_in_date"]),
    checkOutDate: DateTime.parse(json["check_out_date"]),
    eventImage: json["event_image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "event_name": eventName,
    "event_type": eventType,
    "event_location": eventLocation,
    "check_in_date": checkInDate.toIso8601String(),
    "check_out_date": checkOutDate.toIso8601String(),
    "event_image": eventImage,
  };
}
```

I need to get the 'eventName' of item to fetch from my ListView.builder, This is what I've come up with

```
class EventAPI extends BaseAPI {

  Future<List<Event>> fetchAllEvents() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(super.allEventsPath), headers: super.headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      return parsed.map<Event>((json) => Event.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load Events');

    }
  }

}
```

and its being called on the future builder like this

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(
            future: futureEvent,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                          height: 75,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Center(child: Text("${snapshot.data![index].eventName}"),
                          ),
                      )
                  );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

I have tried different methods but still get the same error

My Full Error Is

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class ‘_internal Linked HashMap<String, dynamic>’ has no instance method ‘map’ with matching arguments.
Receiver : _linkedHashMap Len:4
Tried calling map<Event>(Closure: (dynamic) => Event)
Found: map<Y0,Y1>({X0,X1}) => MapEntry<Y0,Y1>) => Map<Y0,Y1>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the actual text of the full error message, rather than just the snippet in the title of your question.

Comment: The full error message I got:

NoSuchMethodError: Class ‘_internal Linked HashMap<String, dynamic>’ has no instance method ‘map’ with matching arguments.
Receiver : _linkedHashMap Len:4
Tried calling map<Event>(Closure: (dynamic) => Event)
Found: map<Y0,Y1>({X0,X1}) => MapEntry<Y0,Y1>) => Map<Y0,Y1>

Comment: @Maks you can view the full error now Thanks

Comment: sorry I meant the stack trace for the error, so we can at least see what line in the code that you posted is the cause of the error.